# What does BitmapFactory.Options do?

Tags: android

What does BitmapFactory.Options in android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options do?

There is no theoretical explanation in the android sdk reference manual about this class, it only contains the explanation about the methods of the class.

Comment: What about this - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html ? It has only one public method and it's `requestCancelDecode`.

Comment: yes, that contains only summary about the fields and the method.

Comment: Then I guess what you need is a tutorial - right?

Comment: Here's a tip - > http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html and another small tut I found, used for image scaling -> http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/03/resize-bitmap-bitmapcreatescaledbitmap.html

Answer (score 2):

Bitmapfactory is mainly used for Scaling

```
Bitmap lBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.Drawable.ic_dolphin);
```

It gets the "dolpin" image and it will reduce the image size, if we dnt use bitmapfactory then it leads to insufficient memory allocations

Answer (score 0):

It's used to pass options to the BitmapFactory - as you might expect :)

For example, you can use it to explicitly scale the Bitmap up or down from the source.

Answer (score 0):

**See this example**

*This method is used to create bitmap of given specific size which is stored in sdcard.*

```
public Bitmap decodeFile(String path,int size) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = size;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: What is the use of REQUIRED_SIZE here? Can we create an image with height>width or width>height, i.e. maintaining the aspect ratio of original image?

Comment: Suppose if you pass size = 200 it this method will try to get bitmap of 200x200. It will maintain the aspect ratio by considering the max(width,height). So your image will not crop or starched.